# updating positions based on speed and direction

Tags: python, simulate

I have completed a pset from an online course, We created random bots that randomly moved around a grid cleaning tiles.
I wanted to create a bot that sequentially cleans each tile and have achieved that when I set the speed to 1.0.

However when I increase the speed by 1, the bot moves two places instead of one, increasing movement in direct relation to each increase.

Here is the class that calculates the new positions:

```
class Pos(object):
    """
    A Position represents a location in a two-dimensional room.
    """

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """
        Initializes a position with coordinates (x, y).
        """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        return self.y

    def getNewPos(self, angle, speed):
        """
        Computes and returns the new Position after a single clock-tick has
        passed, with this object as the current position, and with the
        specified angle and speed.

        Does NOT test whether the returned position fits inside the room.

        angle: number representing angle in degrees, 0 <= angle < 360
        speed: positive float representing speed

        Returns: a Po sobject representing the new position.
        """
        old_x, old_y = self.getX(), self.getY()
        angle = float(angle)
        # Compute the change in position
        delta_y = speed * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
        delta_x = speed * math.sin(math.radians(angle))
        # Add that to the existing position
        new_x = old_x + delta_x
        new_y = old_y + delta_y
        return Position(new_x, new_y)

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%0.2f, %0.2f)" % (self.x, self.y)
```

What is the relation between the speed and the amount that the bot moves, I thought that increasing speed would increase  the speed that he moved and still consider to have crossed over each position but obviously that is incorrect.

Could someone explain exactly how the calculations work, I have not used sin,cos etc for a very long time, can this be altered to achieve what I need or do I need something very different?

Answer (score 1):

You code assumes **time delta** is the same on each call(i.e on each time calling the **getNewPos** method, it assumes the same amount of time has passed. say 1 sec)

Therefore, when the speed is say **1 unit/sec**, then upon each call your position will change by **1 unit**. However, if you set your speed to **2 units/sec**, then the position will be changed by **2 units** on each call, thus skipping every other location.

Comment: thanks, do I need a completely different approach, something where velocity is calculated instead of how this works, sorry if I am not very clear, I have very little experience with this.

Comment: in your context, what you really want to increase is **time resolution** (i.e **decrease time-delta**). Increase speed, on the contrary, increases distance spanned for each time delta

Comment: how  would I do that, I really am clueless with this

Comment: lol that is not in the `Pos` class you posted :) You need to trace your other parts of the code to see how Pos is used. Look for when `getNewPos` gets called

Comment: lol that could be a fun exercise. self.robot_position.getNewPosition(self.robot_direction, self.speed), that is how I calculate a new position, how does that relate? I have set the direction to be up left right and down based on where the last position was.